# How to see what has changed in a patched binary?

Tags: patching, patch-reversing, osx, hopper

I am exploring MacOS Deckset app.
It has a trial version available on the official website.
But there's a cracked version available on torrent trackers.

I want to know what was changed by the people who cracked that app: strings? symbols? few assembly instructions?

Both (genuine and cracked) versions are available as .DMG installers.
I've extracted Deckset.app containers from both of them.

Now, I'm able to explore `Deckset.app/Contents/MacOS/Deckset` binary in `Hopper` tool.
But as the cracked version is patched, I want to understand what actually was patched.
For this, I used `radiff2` tool from `Radare2` toolset:

```
radiff2 genuine.app/Contents/MacOS/Deckset cracked.app/Contents/MacOS/Deckset  > bin_diff.txt
```

It gave me output like this:

```
0x00000e98 901e => 101c 0x00000e98
0x0000201c 109a => 9097 0x0000201c
0x0027d486 770c => 585e 0x0027d486
0x0027d48b 04 => 03 0x0027d48b
0x0027d493 2c => 24 0x0027d493
0x0027d49a 511a => 5097 0x0027d49a
0x0027d49d 00 => 01 0x0027d49d
0x0027d49f 05 => 00 0x0027d49f
0x0027d4a3 fe00010000 => 07fade0c02 0x0027d4a3
0x0027d4aa 53bcfade0c02 => 507300020100 0x0027d4aa
0x0027d4b2 50ee => 0000 0x0027d4b2
0x0027d4b5 020500 => 0000b3 0x0027d4b5
0x0027d4b9 01 => 00 0x0027d4b9
0x0027d4bb 00 => 30 0x0027d4bb
0x0027d4be 012e => 0003 0x0027d4be
0x0027d4c2 0060 => 027e 0x0027d4c2
```

Now, when I open "genuine" app in Hopper, and search for either `0x00000e98`, or `901e`, or `101c`, it gives nothing useful.

E.g. when I do `Menu > Navigate > Go to Address or Symbol` and enter `0x00000e98`, it gives me such segment:

[image]
I don't see nor `901e`, neither `101c` in this segment.

What am I doing wrong?
Do you know better tools for doing this (except IDA Pro, because it's expensive)?

Comment: There is `901e` at the offset `0x00000e98`, though it is in little endian, so it is displayed as `1e90` in "amount to map from the file" line. You are using the right tools. Good luck with your investigation. :)

Comment: Try BinDiff for Ghidra